# Users added to team in Azure DevOps doesn't see any in board

Tags: azure-devops

I have a strange issue with Azure DevOps boards. I create a team and add some person to this team and all is okay, but when I add a new person to this team - they don't see any in the Board(they see only an empty board). I checked permissions in the areas and spacers and it looks like all teams have the same permission. Could you provide some consultation on what I can search for next?

[image]

Comment: 1. Please check whether project admin can see any work item in the current team. 2. Please check if the affected users can't see all teams' boards or only the current team’s boards? 3. Please ask one affected user to create a new work item in the current team's boards and confirm with other affected users if they can see the new created one.

Comment: Khmm when user try to  create post have error tf237111 - I wilL try to check permission maybe I forgot provide some permissions

Comment: See the prerequisites to create work items and use Boards from [View and add work items using the Work Items page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [Use your Kanban board](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-quickstart?view=azure-devops). If there is still teh same issue, please help clarify the above questions to help narrow down the issue.

Comment: I made both guys admins and they an see the board...so I continue to investigate permissions settings....

Comment: Have you figured out which permission is related to this issue? If not, please add the affected users to Contributors group and check if it works.